# Book from a trilogy where a man is sent from the realm of the gods to retrieve his stolen brother

Tags: story-identification, books

In the book the main character is a man who has been sent from the realm of the gods to retrieve his older brother who was stolen and taken through a portal that his parents couldn't pass through.  His brother has since turned evil and imprisoned in an in between realm guarded by a female guardian.  The main character falls in love with a girl who is able to practice magic, but as part of a treaty all the magic users who I think are female have to put a gemstone on their forehead where it attaches and can't be removed that stops them from being able to anything with their magic.

The girl he falls in love with at one point is raped by an inquisitor basically who then gets his junk cut off.  The god and the girl end up having triplets who are separated and sent off although none of them know about the last son as there is a boy, a girl then a boy.  A lot of this takes place around a magical forest.  The god is punished for practicing magic by stoning and as far as everyone is concerned he is dead although he isn't for a reason I don't remember.

The girl he is in love with ends up marrying the king and helps to raise the kings illegitimate son who is now next in line for the throne.  In the last book it's through the help of the god, his love and their three children that they are able to defeat the other god, and when though go back home to the realm of the gods at the end they get turned back into children.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a really good description, however, note that if you want to add anything else, for example when you read this and how old they are, then you can [edit] your question to include any extra details or change what you have so far. You also may want to take the [tour] to learn a little more about the site!